# How to find a view for a certain table in Informix?

Tags: datatable, view, informix

I have a database with loads of tables and views and I want to find out which view belongs to a certain table if this is even possible. The database I use is IBM Informix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you seek is encoded in the [`"informix".sysdepend`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/14.10?topic=tables-sysdepend) table in the system catalog.

**Table 1. SYSDEPEND table column descriptions**

| Column. | Type. | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `btabid` | INTEGER | Code uniquely identifying the base table or view |
| `btype` | CHAR(1) | Base object type: T = Table V = View |
| `dtabid` | INTEGER | Code uniquely identifying a dependent table or view |
| `dtype` | CHAR(1) | Code for the type of dependent object; currently, only view (V = View) is implemented |

So, given the `tabid` value from `"informix".systables` (which might identify a base table or a view), you can find out which other views depend on it.  You will probably need to join with `systables` several times.

For example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SysDepend;
```

| btabid | btype | dtabid | dtype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INTEGER | CHAR(1) | INTEGER | CHAR(1) |
| 30 | T | 70 | V |
| 3 | T | 71 | V |
| 296 | T | 299 | V |
| 297 | T | 300 | V |
| 298 | T | 301 | V |
| 318 | T | 320 | V |
| 318 | T | 325 | V |

```sql
SELECT d.btabid, t1.owner, t1.tabname, d.btype, d.dtabid, d.dtype, t1.owner, t2.tabname
  FROM "informix".SysDepend AS d
  JOIN "informix".SysTables AS t1 ON d.btabid = t1.tabid
  JOIN "informix".SysTables AS t2 ON d.dtabid = t2.tabid
  ORDER BY t1.owner, t1.tabname, t2.owner, t2.tabname;
```

| btabid | owner | tabname | btype | dtabid | dtype | owner | tabname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INTEGER | CHAR(32) | VARCHAR(128) | CHAR(1) | INTEGER | CHAR(1) | CHAR(32) | VARCHAR(128) |
| 298 | informix | sysbldiprovided | T | 301 | V | informix | bldi_provided |
| 297 | informix | sysbldirequired | T | 300 | V | informix | bldi_required |
| 296 | informix | sysbldregistered | T | 299 | V | informix | bld_registered |
| 3 | informix | sysindices | T | 71 | V | informix | sysindexes |
| 30 | informix | sysxtdtypes | T | 70 | V | informix | sysdomains |
| 318 | sde | spatial_references | T | 320 | V | sde | spatial_ref_sys |
| 318 | sde | spatial_references | T | 325 | V | sde | spatial_references_expand |

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer gave me what I want.